# Quicksort algorithm not working in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I have a pseudo code of a Quicksort in my book, that I am following step-by-step. But the end output is not what I want. I have turned it into this code:

```
public class quickSort {

    public int[] quick(int[] A, int p, int r){
        int q;
        if(p<r){
            q = partition(A, p, r);
            //First partition comfirmed to "work"
            quick(A, p, q-1);
            quick(A, q+1, r);
        }
        return A;
    }

    public int partition(int[] A, int p, int r){

        int x = A[r];
        int i = p-1;
        int temp;

        for(int j=p; j<r-1; j++){
            if(A[j]<=x){
                i = i+1;
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        temp = A[i+1];
        A[i+1] = A[r];
        A[r] = temp;

        return i+1;
    }

}
```

My book illustrates how the first partition is being handled. With the input:

```
2 8 7 1 3 5 6 4
```

.. the first partition "sorts" this into

```
2 1 3 4 7 5 6 8
```

.. and this I have comfirmed. And so, if this work, and it is just calling itself with smaller parts to do the exact same thing, why is it in the end giving the output:

```
2 3 1 4 5 7 8 7
```

.. and not something that is sorted???

Comment: There is a strong java convention that class names start with upper case, and variables with lower case. According to it, your class should be named `QuickSort`, and the array should NOT be `A`. It won't solve your problem, but it will make the code more readable for java developers.

Comment: Fair enough, Ill be sure to get that stuff right from now on. I called it A to copy my book from every step, and not make any mistakes that way.

Comment: The 1-letter variable names certainly don't help readability either. I wouldn't say `A` is a particularly bad name as I can't really think of a descriptive alternative, but (presumably) p -> start, r -> finish, x -> pivot, i -> left, j -> right (or something like that).

Comment: Yep, critisism taken. I will make these changes for next time. Ty

Comment: Whoever voted to close as "too broad"; please consider retracting your vote to remove this from the queue. The question is not ideal, but it's not too broad, and succinct answers were given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that only elements `[p, r-2]` are going to be processed in `public int partition()` instead of `[p, r-1]`. A[r-1] might happen to be less than pivot, but it is not swapped and stays in its place

Comment: You are totally right! On closer inspection, the pseudo code says "for j = p to r-1", which should obviously include r-1. How annoying! Using "j<r" or "j<=r-1" makes it work. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so here's your answer tweaked and it works:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class QuickSort
{
  public QuickSort()
  {
    int array[] = { 2, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4 };
    quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
  }

  void quickSort(int[] array, int p, int r)
  {
    if (p < r)
    {
      int q = partition(array, p, r);
      quickSort(array, p, q - 1);
      quickSort(array, q + 1, r);
    }
  }

  int partition(int array[], int p, int r)
  {
    int x = array[r];
    int i = p - 1;

    for (int j = p; j < r; j++)
    {
      if (array[j] <= x)
      {
        i += 1;

        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
      }
    }

    int temp = array[i + 1];
    array[i + 1] = array[r];
    array[r] = temp;

    return i + 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new QuickSort();
  }
}
```

But by now I'm sure you got to know what went wrong. I had to keep my word though and that's why I'm updating my answer here.

Comment: Yeah, I remember that one from top search on Google, and it works. But I wont learn anything if I dont figure out whats wrong with the one I wrote, cause in my mind it should work. Thanks anyway though :]

Comment: -1 - it seems this is a your (or someone's else) implementation, and not pointing out what's the problem in the OP's solution. This is definetly not the point of this question. The OP wants to find out why HIS solution fails.

Comment: Who the heck upvoted this copy-paste answer? (which is not an answer..)

Comment: @mathkid91: So do you want to understand how QuickSort works or why your particular code is not working? Cause I can update my answer appropriately then.

Comment: Why mine does not work :) I get the idea of how Quicksort operates.

Comment: Credit for "your" "answer" (not an answer and not yours) goes to [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html). I am usually not that rude, but this is the least amount of effort I have seen put into an "answer" for ages.

Comment: Figured out, but I still appreciate your effort. Thanks a lot :))

Answer (score 0):

it should be **for(int j=p; j<=r-1; j++)**

```
public int partition(int[] A, int p, int r){

int x = A[r];
int i = p-1;
int temp;

for(int j=p; j<=r-1; j++){
    if(A[j]<=x){
        i = i+1;
        temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
    }       
}
temp = A[i+1];
A[i+1] = A[r];
A[r] = temp;

return i+1;
```

}